# World of Warcraft with wine (DirectX error)

Tags: 11.10, wine

I've just installed Ubuntu this night, however starting WoW will give me a directx error.

I have installed DirectX through the normal installer and through/with CrossOver.
[image: Screesnhot of error]

How can this be resolved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing WoW through playonlinux (which you can find in the default repositories or [here](http://www.playonlinux.com/)). If that does not help, have a look at the [WineHQ database concerning WoW](http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=1922). In both cases, make sure that you are using Wine >=1.3.x.

Comment: Ouch, I was running 1.3.28 however I've updated to 1.4 now and it works. Cheers =)